# Libgdx Bullet getRayFromWorld() broken

Tags: java, libgdx, bullet, raycasting

Okay, so I am not sure what point I updated from, but I grabbed the newest nightly tried to recompile my code to find

```
callback.getRayFromWorld().setValue(rayFrom.x, rayFrom.y, rayFrom.z);
callback.getRayToWorld().setValue(rayTo.x, rayTo.y, rayTo.z);
```

was broken, so I tried

```
callback.getRayFromWorld(rayFrom);
callback.getRayToWorld(rayTo);
```

to no avail. checking the libgdx github I couldn't understand what had changed.
Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "broken"? Does not compile, throws an exception, computes wrong result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getRayFromWorld` will set the specified vector to the rayFrom (it will *get* the vector). You'll want to use `setRayFromWorld` instead:

```
callback.setRayFromWorld(rayFrom);
callback.setRayToWorld(rayTo);
```

For more info on this change, see: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/2176#issuecomment-50459926

Comment: Thanks for the help. I knew it would be something simple like that just couldn't find it